# QGIS MapTiler Stamen Toner basemap missing highway/motorway labels

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, basemap, maptiler, stamen

I have been struggling to get the MapTiler basemap to produce the labeling I need. I want to show the Stamen Toner basemap, and I want to only show the interstate highway labels — no other roads.

I understand that this should be a matter of telling the basemap to display the label for the class 'motorway', but I cannot get it to work. I have even tried to see what shows up when there are no filters used for road labels, and every single road gets a label, except for the interstate highway. See below, this setting, which I believe should show every road label (space permitting), based on the settings I have, also below. This map now shows local road and highway labels, but not the interstate highway (running from upper-middle/left to lower-middle). What am I missing here?[image] [image]

Comment: Add the screenshot again!